# Get outgoing port number from urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using Python 2.6.x and urllib2 to do some web scraping, but I need really low-level socket information (really just the port number of the local socket) for each HTTP request. Does anyone know how to get that?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Okay, I'm still trying to get this right, so I did what I thought should work but I'm not getting the output when I try and use the new stuff. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from urllib2 import *

class AbstractHTTPHandler(AbstractHTTPHandler):

    def do_open(self, http_class, req):
        """
          ...copy docstring...
        """
        print "woot!"
        ...copy code from urllib2.AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open...
```

Comment: In response to the edit: You must actually replace the handlers, and not only define your own new one. Also, I strongly recommend naming your subclass differently then `AbstractHTTPHandler`, and using `import urllib2` instead of `from urllib2 import *`. Otherwise, it won't be clear which name comes from which module.

Comment: My intention was to be able to swap out the module entirely, but it looks like I won't be able to do that without copying the whole file. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urllib2 can operate on different URL schemes, which may not even have a notion of socket. Instead, use [`http.client`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)'s *undocumented* `sock` property:

```
try:
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
except ImportError: # Python<3
    from httplib import HTTPConnection

h = HTTPConnection('example.net', 80)
h.request('GET', '/')
print('Local port: ' + str(h.sock.getsockname()[1]))
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if I can swap out the library I'm using at this point, but I will look into it. I'd still like to be able to access this information from the `urllib2.OpenerDirector` object (maybe it uses HTTPConnection in its workings and I could wrap it?), but I may not be able to.

Comment: If you are willing to write your own handler, you can certainly capture the `HTTPConnection` object. It's the first argument of `AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open` (and subclasses), but it never gets stored anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. I'm thinking of writing an extension of `urllib2 ` and just overriding the `AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open` method to spit out the logging I want. That's really all that's needed anyway.